# Using CASE statement in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I have following table

```
A   B    C
20  20   23
20  20   20
20  21   22
13  14   30
```

named triangles and I need to each time output if the triangle is Equilateral, Isosceles, Scalene or not a triangle.
I used the following code :

```
select A,B,C,
case
when A = B = C then'Equilateral' 
when A + B < C then "Not A Triangle"
when (A = B and B != C) or (A = C and B != A) or ( B = C and A != B ) then "Isoceles"
else "Scalene"
end,  
from Triangles;
```

but I get this error :

```
when A = B = C then'Equilateral' 
* 
ERROR at line 3: 
ORA-00905: missing keyword
```

Comment: Replace `A = B = C` with `A = B AND B = C`. Remove also a semicolon between `end` and `from` keywords from here: ` .... end,  from ....`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you have to put those separately as `A = B` and `B = C` and remove the `,` after the `end` (because you no more columns)

```
select A,B,C,
       case
         when A = B and B = C then'Equilateral' 
         when A + B < C then 'Not A Triangle'
         when (A = B and B != C) or (A = C and B != A) or ( B = C and A != B ) then 'Isoceles'
         else 'Scalene'
       end
from Triangles;
```

Comment: yeah that worked , thank you

Comment: Did it work @Mohamed? I'd expect this to fail unless you have a column named `Not A Triangle` (exactly the same casing) in TRIANGLES. Double quotes are for cased object names.

Comment: Changed to single quotes to be safe. Thanks!

Comment: For Isoceles you don't have to check if 3rd side is not equal to other ones. If they are, case statement will already end in first check. {A = B and B = C}

Comment: @Ben i actually used single quotes in the actual query , thank you for the observation

Comment: @EdgarsT. yeah good point

Comment: btw guys , does any of you know how do i not display the columns before the string ? ( i.e i want my display to look like this "equilateral" not like this "20 20 20 equilateral "

Comment: I hope you are joking, and it is not as easy as removing "A,B,C," from select statement.